# Changing the z-index of a div when a function is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When createCustomerCard('CUST_0') is called it opens the first order card below

```
<div id="CUST_0" class="widget ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable" style="width: 500px; height: auto; font-size: 11px; display: block; left: 29px; top: 156px; z-index: 1013; ">
```

with z-index of 1013, but if you try call the same function its either not drawing the customer card or not increasing the z-index beacause if a CUST_01 card is created the z-index is above the z-index of CUST_0. is there a way to increase the z-index by 1 for a div id when the function is called?

CUST_2 example below

```
<div id="CUST_2" class="widget ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable" style="width: 500px; height: auto; font-size: 11px; display: block; z-index: 1014; left: 319px; top: 162px; ">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to style `position:relative` says @Mr Lister or `position:absolute`:

```
<div id="CUST_0" class="widget ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable" style="width: 500px; height: auto; font-size: 11px; display: block; left: 29px; top: 156px; position:relative;z-index: 1013; ">
```

and add jQuery where is the function called:

```
$('#CUST_N').css("z-index", $('#CUST_N').css("z-index")+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the div have a `position` other than `static`? Only positioned elements can use z-indexes. So give it `position:relative` and it might just work.

By the way, why `z-index:1013`? What's special about that number?

Comment: It's incrementing from a starting value of z-index: 999; from somewhere :)

Answer (score 2):

This should increase the z-index by 1:

```
$('#CUST_N').css("z-index", "+=1");
```