# change the z-index of multiple div using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are multiple `div` to which I want to apply different `z-index` like below:

```
<div class="container" style="z-index:4">
 </div>
<div class="container" style="z-index:3">
 </div>
<div class="container" style="z-index:2">
 </div>
<div class="container" style="z-index:1">
 </div>
```

**EDIT**: Using above code the box-shadow is able to display. Output is like [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/vLh7c690/1/). In this case I need to write `z-index` manually to each `div` so I am trying to make it lets say automatic. I thought this will be possible with JS or Jquery.

So, here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/m3923k1x/3/) on which I am trying to give `z-index` using javascript. But its not working.

Here as below, I found some references but I am not able to apply it.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794606/jquery-z-index-manipulation-auto-value-instead-number) , [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568158/changing-z-index-to-make-a-clicked-div-appear-on-top), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857359/how-to-change-the-z-index-of-list-items-in-a-menu-with-jquery), [Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687693/changing-the-z-index-of-a-div-when-a-function-is-called)

How do I apply different `z-index` to multiple `div` using javascript or jquery? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not included jquery on your jsFiddle and try this:

```
$(function() {
  var boxes = $("div");
  var z = 4;
    boxes.each(function() {
        $(this).zIndex(z--);
    });
});
```

Also include jquery UI.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m3923k1x/9/)

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Have you checked your DEMO code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @ Brijesh Bhatt: thanks for your reply. But still the output is not as expected. :( It should be like this jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/m3923k1x/3

Comment: Sorry, I have given wrong Output link here in comment only. Right expected output should be like this http://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/vLh7c690/1/.

Comment: @ Brijesh Bhatt: yes, that's it. thanks a lot. So I was missing `jquery 1.7.2` and `jquery UI 1.8.18` in my code? and I have doubt. why its not working for `z++` that is for `z` increment keeping `z=0` as it will also get different `z-index` apply to `div`?

Comment: @kiran it is because divs are being iterated sequentially on a page and `z-index` was sequentially decremented as in your updated fiddle so we must assign the `z-index` in reverse as 4,3,2,1 to div1,div2,div3,div4.. I hope you understand..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77150/discussion-between-kiran-and-brijesh-bhatt).

Answer (score 4):

With the premise that you must include jQuery to properly run your jQuery code, inside the `each()` you need to assign the `z-index` to the current element, and not to the whole `$('.container')` selection.

Without an extra call to the `$()` function you can assign the value like so:

```
boxes.each(function() {
    this.style.zIndex = z++;
});
```

You could also avoid at all jQuery and use vanillaJS with `forEach()`

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('container'), function(el, i) {
    el.style.zIndex = i;  
   /* you can use the position <i> of the node inside 
      the <nodeCollection> to set the z-index */

   console.log(el);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m3923k1x/8/

The output of the `console.log(el)`, as expected, is

[image]

---

If you need instead to assign z-index in **reverse** order, as in your example, you can try like so

```
var lastZIndex = document.getElementsByClassName('container').length - 1;
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('container'), function(el, i) {
   el.style.zIndex = lastZIndex - i;  
   console.log(el);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0tae1z7d/1/

The result now is

[image]

Comment: @ Fabrizio Calderan : thanks for your reply. actually the output should be look like this http://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/m3923k1x/3/. please check the my EDIT in question.

Comment: Sorry, I have given wrong Output link here in comment only. Right expected output should be like this http://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/vLh7c690/1/.

Comment: just change `lastZIndex = document.getElementsByClassName('container').length;`

Comment: @ Fabrizio Calderan: Can you please let me know, why the output is different by both ways that you had shown? As the `z-index` are different in both cases but just the matter of order which is different.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to include jQuery library in your jsfiddle
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 </div>
<div class="container">
 </div>
<div class="container">
 </div>
<div class="container">
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
     box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.container:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: yellow;
}
.container:nth-child(even){
    background-color: white;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var boxes = $("div");
    var z = 0;
        boxes.each(function() {
             this.style.zIndex = z++;
        });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3923k1x/5/)

**EDIT**:

If you need reverse order of z-index though, you can adjust a jQuery a bit, like so:
jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var boxes = $("div");
    var z = boxes.length;
        boxes.each(function() {
             this.style.zIndex = z--;
        });

});
```

So instead of starting point of var z to be set to zero, you're assigning it to number of elements held by var boxes, and instead of incrementing z, you decrementing it as in this new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3923k1x/10/)

Comment: @ robjez: thanks for your reply. But still the output is not as expected. :( It should be like this http://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/m3923k1x/3/

Comment: @kiran - am I misunderstanding something? - code form your link doesn't apply z-index at all. See that in a web inspector (F12 in Chrome). Watch your div's there are not having inline style applied

Comment: @ robjez: Sorry, I have given wrong Output link here in comment only. Right expected output should be like this http://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/vLh7c690/1/ , which is given in the question EDIT section.

Comment: @ robjez: thanks for the edit. now result is what I was expecting. Others friends here also have answered this before but I did not get why only reverse order is working here i.e decrement order not increment order? I had used decrement order just for example. this doubt i had asked to others also but did not get satisfactory answer. could you please able to explain?

Comment: @kiran - I think it works for both cases: decreasing and incresing. It's up to you if you want to have your div's z-indexed in the order of highest to lowest (as in my edit), or lowest to highest (as per my original answer). This is totally up to you, and depends of your requirements here.

Comment: @ robjez: working means I was saying box-shadow in output that I was looking for. please check box-shadow difference of output between two jsfiddle of your answer. then please check my doubt.

Comment: @kiran - this is absolutely normal behaviour - highest z-index, closer it is to us in z-axis. So in first scenario you won't see box-shadows because they are covered by elements with higher z-index of element below. You can show them though by changing your `margin-bottom` to ie `3px` for `div.container`